# jQuery Не работает плавный скролл якоря при переходе на другую страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу сделать якорь с плавной прокруткой по внешней ссылке. Логика примерно в следующем: находимся на одной странице, кликаем на ссылку с якорем, нас направляет на другую страницу где плавно скроллит к нужному элементу (див с названием якоря)

Сам якорь сделать конечно же получилось, но вот с плавной прокруткой - не вышло. Событие использовал и он-клик и лоад

Подскажите, если знаете в чём проблема

```js
jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
                var myHash = location.hash; 
                //location.hash = ''; //очищаем хеш
                if (myHash[1] != undefined) { 
                    var $target = myHash.substr(1);
                    $target = jQuery('[name=' + $target + ']');
                    jQuery("html, body").animate({
                        scrollTop: $target.offset().top + "px"
                    }, {
                        duration: 1500,
                        easing: "swing"
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

P.S. Если перезагрузить страницу, плавный скролл сработает, но если перейти по ссылке - нет

Comment: Возможно ли добавить небольшую задержку миллисекунд 500?

Comment: После перезагрузки браузер сам по умолчанию скролит к вашему якорю еще до события load. Советую сделать следующий воркэраунд. Если у вас якорь с именем `anchor`, то делайте ссылку с хешем `#smooth-anchor`. Тогда браузер не перейдет на этот якорь. А в событии `load` проверяйте хеш, и если он начинается с символов `#smooth-` то удаляйте их, а остальной кусок хеша - `anchor` будет реальным именем якоря, на который нужно скролить программно.